# Easy deployment for C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, windows-server-2012

I have a C# MVC application that uses an SQL database. I need to make this as easy to install/run as possible as it will be being run by people with no experience hosting web applications. The people that will be managing this are able to build servers with a base windows install (Windows2k12, 2k8, ect..) but have no experience with IIS or SQL. I can set it up for them but in the future if it needs to be re-installed I won't be around.

Comment: Look into web deploy.

Comment: I did but it appears that still requires they install MSSQL, IIS, set up the site in IIS, and set up the database/database user.

Comment: You can supplement it with scripting (powershell/SQL), or wix might simplify things. Alternatively maybe they could use an external host if that's an option for your site.

Comment: I'll look into powershell and wix. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your options, setting up an automation server such as [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/) to handle deployments would work.  After setting up a deployment job anyone with permission can deploy with the push of a button.  Doesn't get much easier than that.  It's been a little while since I've set up an MVC Jenkins project but [this blog post](https://blog.couchbase.com/continuous-deployment-with-jenkins-and-net/) looks like a pretty good overview of how to set it up.

One of the downsides is that they'd have to keep the server running and make sure that they have a full backup available in case something happens.  I'm guessing if you're trying to help them deploy the app in the first place, then they aren't going to be able to set a Jenkins server back up from scratch.  But at the end of the day, if something blows up, regardless of what you set up for them, they're going to have to do something to fix it.

EDIT: Just read your other comment, didn't catch they'd need to completely rebuild from scratch (assuming little to no backups).  I believe you can automate most of the IIS config and some of the SQL Server setup with Powershell, which can also run on Jenkins I believe.  I've never done that myself, though.  [Here](https://hodgkins.io/automating-with-jenkins-and-powershell-on-windows-part-1) is another blog post on the matter that might be able to help, though.

Comment: Thank you that might work, I haven't worked with automating using powershell I'll look into that more.